# Java event listener

Tags: java, events, event-listener

Hii i have some question about Java event listener... i have some experience with this but in school i learn other way and i have to ask... here is code

> ```
>  lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
>
>       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
>
>            ((Label)e.getComponent()).setText("Mouse clicked");
>
>        }});
> ```

why i need to use "e.getComponent" when i know is "lbl"...i try without and work same way...

> ```
>  lbl.setText("Mouse clicked");
> ```

or

> ```
>  whatEverLbl.setText("someText");
> ```

before i use this "e.getSource" when i make one method for multiple button...like

> if ((e.getSource) == "testButton")....

but why i need that in previous example...
and are "e.getSource" and "e.getComponent" are same... or equal because i try and both are work...

Sory if i make mistakes in spell...

Comment: Mr. Крстић, is it swing, awt, JavaFx or some other GUI?

Comment: You do not have to use e.getComponent. Use lbl if you want to. In your example they might all be the same — but this might not always be the case (consider the case where your listener is on a component that has got child components where the click actually originated).

Comment: About getSource / getComponent. They will probably always be the same, one of them are from the base class EventObject and one of them are from the base class ComponentEvent. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent() and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource().

Comment: is swing @zlakad

Answer (score 1):

First, start by looking at [`MouseEvent#getComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent--).  It only returns a `Component`.  So regardless of what you know, the compiler has no idea what the source of the event "might" be.

Remember, these APIs were designed before generics and inner/anonymous class support was available, so all the listener interfaces use to either be implemented by the class itself or by separate class.

> and are "e.getSource" and "e.getComponent" are same

Yes

Another consideration you need to make, is you may have a listener been responsible for monitoring multiple components, perform specialised (or common) tasks for each component.

> why i need to use "e.getComponent" when i know is "lbl"...i try without and work same way...

Okay, again, this comes down to the fact that the listener API pre-dates a number of changes to the language, including generics, inner/anonymous classes and changes to the way the compiler treats local variables referenced from anonymous classes (or more importantly, the way in which the developer no longer needs to mark them as `final`)

So, taking "most" of that into consideration:

- If the anonymous listener is attached to a instance field, it's fair to say you'd use the instance field instead itself
- If the anonymous listener is attached to a instance field, you might consider using the local variable, but, if the local variable is created in a loop, it would be safer to use the event's source, as it removes any ambiguity in your mind
- If the listener is implemented at the class level or via a separate class (even a inner class), it would be safer to use the event's source directly, as the listener might be monitoring a number of different components

Comment: Wow... that is good explanation...i didn't expect this haha thanks broo

Comment: I use getSource() before only in inner class... but now i understend... it's better to use this

Comment: @ilijakrstic There's nothing wrong with `getSource`, but the reality is, I can't think of a situation that the `MouseEvent` wouldn't be based on a `Component` as it's source. `getComponent` is simply a convince method which makes it easier to perform common actions against a `Component`, like, say, changing it's `background` color